# Onclick for custom layout view

Tags: android, view

I have created a custom layout in android, here is the code:

```
View newView;

newView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.userview,newwrapper, false);
```

But my problem is i am not able to add onclick function to this View.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: have you set onclicklistener to newview view object?

Comment: @SharadMhaske there is no such function for view

Comment: then u must get reference to those view in newview object using newview.findviewby(id of view); for all the view that layout file contain.then you can set onclicklistner to all the view.

Comment: @priya : yes, there is. read the doc again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
  newView.setClickable(true);
  newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Hope it helps.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_priority, null);

Button btn = (Button) promptsView .findViewById(...);
btn.setOnClickListener(...);
```